# Некорректная кодировка при взаимодействии PHP - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

В своей базе mysql я использую кодировку `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

В конфиге CMS установлена кодировка UTF-8 `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Но если я отправляю запрос через PHP, то в базе получаю следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И наоборот то что в базе отображается нормально, проходя через PHP ломается в итоге.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$pdo = new PDO( 
    'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=defaultDbName', 
    'username', 
    'password', 
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") 
);
```

Comment: У меня уже прописано `mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");`

Comment: PDO - это несколько иное, что у Вас прописано. Но в любом случае - гадать бесполезно, а с той информацией, что Вы представили, получается угадайка. Может и Ваша cms что-то вносит, может еще что-то. Проблема, как Вы спрашиваете, может быть в очень широком диапазоне возможностей.

Answer (score 1):

1. Поля в таблице тоже должны быть `utf8mb4_general_ci`
2. Файл php должен быть в кодировке `utf8`

   CREATE TABLE `table_name`  (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 
         COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   );

Comment: Сравнение: utf8_general_ci